# Proguard how to shrink Facebook sdk

Tags: android, proguard, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Proguard for an Android app.

According to the [example](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html), to shrink .jar files in lib I need to add `-injar libs`.

But what if I want to shrink external sdks such as Facebook? Do I provide the local classpath of it?